# Convertir consulta SQL con WITH a LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, .net, linq

Comunidad tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL server y quiero pasarla a LINQ para trabajarla con .NET, pero no se como trabajar el "with as" en linq

***WITH t1 AS (select idColaborador,idProyecto, sum(Horas) as Horas from RegistroTiempo where FechaRegistro between '2020-12-01' and '2020-12-30'
group by idColaborador,idProyecto) SELECT idColaborador, idProyecto, Horas, (0.0+Horas)/(sum(Horas) OVER (PARTITION BY idColaborador))
as Porcentaje FROM t1  order by  idColaborador,Horas desc***

El resultado que deseo obtener es el siguiente, en el cual obtengo las horas trabajadas en cierto proyecto por un colaborador y el porcentaje de horas correspondiente a ese proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Trata de explicar mejor lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Desconozco si obligatoriamente necesitas realizar la consulta con Linq, pero podrías usar System.Data.SqlClient o el uso de Dapper, para ejecutar la consulta sin pasarla a Linq, saludos y suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Las consultas `WITH` en SQL se pueden tratar como subconsultas. En realidad no es más que una forma de ahorrar escribir varias veces la misma consulta (aunque tiene particularidades como las consultas recursivas que no es tu caso)

Es decir, en esa consulta la parte `WITH` es:

```
select idColaborador,idProyecto, sum(Horas) as Horas 
from RegistroTiempo 
where FechaRegistro between '2020-12-01' and '2020-12-30' 
group by idColaborador,idProyecto
```

con el nombre `T1` (en el `WITH T1 AS`). Sobre esa consulta se hace la otra. Se puede traducir como:

```
SELECT idColaborador, idProyecto, Horas, (0.0+Horas)/(sum(Horas) OVER (PARTITION BY idColaborador)) as Porcentaje 
FROM (select idColaborador,idProyecto, sum(Horas) as Horas 
        from RegistroTiempo 
         where FechaRegistro between '2020-12-01' and '2020-12-30' 
         group by idColaborador,idProyecto) AS t1 
order by idColaborador,Horas desc
```

Por tanto, para pasarlo a LinQ tendrás que hacerlo con una consulta sobre otra consulta